# php preg_replace behaves differently

Tags: php, regex

I have a piece of text in the forum:

```
line one; &#13;
line two; &#13;
line three; &#13;
line four; &#13;
```

(the result was produced by geshi -  $geshi->parse_code();)

I tried to remove "&#13;" using

```
$result2=preg_replace("/&\#13;/", "", $result1);
```

but it is not working.

The strange thing is: this is done successfully in the live php regular expression tester: http://www.phpliveregex.com/

could some expert advise on it?

thanks a lot!

BTW:
I tried `var_dump` and the output does not change except the title changed to string(5411) " see http://saslab.org

I also tried to use `/\r/` to remove the symbols, but in vain.

thank you for all suggestions!

Comment: try `$result2=preg_replace("/&#13;/", "", $result1);`

Comment: What are you getting as output?

Comment: Can you `var_dump` `$result1` and add it t to your question?

Comment: It must be a carriage return. Try `$result2=preg_replace("/\r/", "", $result1);`, or just `$result2 = str_replace("\r", "", $result1)`.

Comment: Why not use `str_replace` ?

Comment: Hi Bart, $result2 = str_replace("\r", "", $result1) wont work.   Hi Jon, I will var_dump.  Hi Avinash, I did as you suggested.  not working.

Comment: Hi Bart, I did use str_replace.  Not working.

Comment: Are you trying to say you want to remove the `&amp;` and `#13;` from `&amp;</span><span style="color: #666666; font-style: italic;">#13;` HTML string?

Comment: Ok, try `str_replace('&amp;#13;', '', $result1)`, or `preg_replace('/&(?:amp;)?((?:\s*<[^<]*>)*)#13;/', '\1', $result1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see if this is what you need:

```
<?php 

$str="line one; &#13;line two; &#13;line three; &#13;line four; &#13;";
$result2 = str_replace("&#13", ":", $str);//replace : with your required string.
echo $result2;

?>
```

Comment: @john then you need to look at your input i.e. `$result1`.because in the given answer there is nothing big that it should not work.